# How to manage different kinds of data in a linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have a project that the teacher asks us to do some operations in a linked list. Okay, they are pretty easy to implement but I'm having trouble to manage the data inside of my list. They can be any of those: int, char, float or string(char array). I know how to link any of those individually but when they're mixed up things start to get messy.

I have not tried much, I'm stuck. Here are some thoughts that passed through my mind: create 4 structs, 1 for each data type (but I've never seen a linked list of different structs, maybe it's not a list by definition because they are not of the same struct type) or create 1 struct with a declaration for every data type. It's important to tell that I have a variable that tells me what type of data I'm managing at that moment (but when I pass the arguments for my function, I don't have all of them, unless I come up with some flags but it seems pretty dumb and the project didn't specify any limitations for my variables).

Sorry for not showing any code, I think that it's not necessary in this case because my ideas are not working. I can show you the results that I expect to have, for example:

Given the data (the first number tells me how many nodes my list has):

5

f 3.14

d 100

c x

s gardenal

d 300

I expect my result to be:

3.1400 100 x gardenal 300

I'm new at this subject and I tried to explicit my ideas of code above. Thank you for reading this far and have a nice Thursday.

Comment: Just use a non typed pointer `void *` into the struct used for the list or an union.

Comment: You're looking for a void pointer.

Comment: I forgot of unions, thank you guys.

Answer (score 5):

In general you need to add a type tag to `struct Node` so that you can track the kind of data stored in the individual nodes.

For storing data you can use a void pointer or you can use a union. If you use a void pointer you'll need casting whenever accessing data. If you use a union every node will end up using memory corresponding to the size of the largest union member.

Here is a simple example **using void pointer**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum ListType 
{
    INT = 0,
    FLOAT,
    CHAR,
    STRING,
};

struct Node
{
    struct Node *next;
    enum ListType type;
    void *data;
};

void printNode(struct Node *p)
{
    switch (p->type)
    {
        case INT:
            printf("%d ", *((int*)p->data));
            break;
        case FLOAT:
            printf("%f ", *((float*)p->data));
            break;
        case CHAR:
            printf("%c ", *((char*)p->data));
            break;
        case STRING:
            printf("%s ", (char*)p->data);
            break;
        default:
            printf("ERROR ");
            break;
    }
}

void printList(struct Node *p)
{
    while(p)
    {
        printNode(p);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

void freeListData(struct Node *p)
{
    while(p)
    {
        free(p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // Build the list manually to illustrate the printing
    struct Node N1;
    struct Node N2;

    N1.type = FLOAT;
    N1.data = malloc(sizeof(float));
    *((float*)N1.data) = 3.14;
    N1.next = &N2;

    N2.type = INT;
    N2.data = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *((int*)N2.data) = 100;
    N2.next = NULL;

    // .. more nodes

    printList(&N1);

    freeListData(&N1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3.140000 100
```

And here is an example **using union**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum ListType 
{
    INT = 0,
    FLOAT,
    CHAR,
    STRING,
};

union ListData
{
    int d;
    float f;
    char c;
    char *str;  // Memory for the string must be malloc'ed
};

struct Node
{
    struct Node *next;
    enum ListType type;
    union ListData data;
};

void printNode(struct Node *p)
{
    switch (p->type)
    {
        case INT:
            printf("%d ", p->data.d);
            break;
        case FLOAT:
            printf("%f ", p->data.f);
            break;
        case CHAR:
            printf("%c ", p->data.c);
            break;
        case STRING:
            printf("%s ", p->data.str);
            break;
        default:
            printf("ERROR ");
            break;
    }
}

void printList(struct Node *p)
{
    while(p)
    {
        printNode(p);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

void freeListStrings(struct Node *p)
{
    while(p)
    {
        if (p->type == STRING) free(p->data.str);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // Build the list manually to illustrate the printing
    struct Node N1;
    struct Node N2;
    struct Node N3;

    N1.type = FLOAT;
    N1.data.f = 3.14;
    N1.next = &N2;

    N2.type = INT;
    N2.data.d = 100;
    N2.next = &N3;

    N3.type = STRING;
    N3.data.str = malloc(sizeof "Hello World");
    strcpy(N3.data.str, "Hello World");
    N3.next = NULL;

    // .. more nodes

    printList(&N1);

    freeListStrings(&N1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3.140000 100 Hello World
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your amazing explanation (and the rest of you too)! Glad to see the brackets format that I like being used by someone :)