# Is there a way in C to point to an array of pointers each of which points to different data types?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I am trying to create an automated template in embedded C, which has a fixed plane text format, interspersed with variable parameters which I need to pick up from say an array. So I am putting in place holders at the point of occurrence of the parameters. Some of the parameters are strings while others are integer values or floating point values.

I have inserted extended ASCII values as place holders and then subtract 0x80 to extract an index based on the point of occurrence of the place holder. But I don't have a way to point to different source tables yet.

Comment: After re-reading your question - you're going to have to be more clear before anyone can answer anything. It's not even clear what you're asking - your content doesn't seem to line up with your title.

Comment: Can you use a struct, or if required arrays of struct?

Comment: *I have inserted extended ASCII values as place holders*. Phew... That is really a brave method. But it will also limit **for life** you code to ASCII only string with no portability to any non english language, and no possibility to use any typographic unicode character like left and right quotation marks: `”` U+201d, `“` U+201c, `’` U+2019, `‘` U+2018 which are now common in HTML pages. Think to that twice... In addition, using true placeholders like `{...}` could allow to pass type or formatting information in the template itself.

Comment: See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56059015/4386427 It stores the "generic data" in a linked list but the principle is just the same if you want an array. The second solution using a union is the one I would prefer.

Comment: Array of pointers to union of structs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition Array is collection of similar data types. So there is no no straight forward way in which you can have a array of pointers to different data types.

One of the way by which you can achieve this is by `type casting` the array elements with intended data types while accessing/ de-referencing the elements.

To know the correct  `type` while accessing the elements you need to store the type while defining the element.

A possible solution could look like this:

```
typedef struct
{
   int type; //0 - enumDay, 1 - Struct C etc
   void* data;
}mydata_t;

mydata_t myarray[10];
```

**Assigning :**

```
myarray[0].type = 2; //Lets assume 2 for string
myarray[0].data = "My String";
```

**Using :**

```
 if( myarray[0].type == 2) // is it a string?
 {
    printf("This is the string :%s \n",(char*)myarray[0].Data);
 }
```

Comment: Quote: "Only way by which you can achieve this is..." Well, there are other ways, e.g. using a union.